# asyncio iterable processing using concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor as executor for loop.run_in_executor()

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm using asyncio to do message handling in my application. It receives a message, and determines the actions that will be run in a ProcessPoolExecutor instance. On the one hand, the documentation for `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` supports the idea of chunking an iterable to run them in parallel on the different worker processes. On the other hand, `loop.run_in_executor` passes the arguments as `*args` and doesn't mention anything about iterable processing.

How do I pass an iterable to `loop.run_in_executor` for chunking as in the basic `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` usage?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor

Comment: The run_in_executor doc example doesn't show the application of an iterable argument to the process pool though. The docs just reference *args (i.e. multiple positional arguments) without regard for their properties.

Comment: That was a hint for you, it contains another link to https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor where `map(func, *iterables, timeout=None, chunksize=1)` is there and (*Changed in version 3.5: Added the chunksize argument.*)

Comment: Ah I think I understand. I'm not sure why it didn't occur to me to call the executor method (`pool.map()` or whatever) in loop.run_in_executor() instead of my target function directly. I've already used this concept elsewhere, just approached it from a different angle.